# Position categoryAxis beneath min column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dataviz

Is it possible to position the Kendo categoryAxis beneath the min column?

see also this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/An59E/182/

```
categoryAxis: {
                field: "Month",    
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                line: {
                    width: 1.5,
                    color: "black"
                }
            }
```

Thx a lot!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `axisCrossingValue`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.axisCrossingValue

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/An59E/184/)**

If you still want a line at Zero, you could apply a PlotBand:

> **[PlotBand Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/An59E/185/)**